# log out strews primesfaces' components

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

When I click on log out button, primefaces' components are strewed before the login.xhtml page appears !
the `action` property calls the `logout()` function.

the source code of the `logout()` function is :

```
public String logout() throws IOException
{
    HttpServletRequest request = ((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest());
    request.getSession().removeAttribute("userManager");
    request.getSession().invalidate();
    return "../login.xhtml";
}
```

I used `<p:dock>` with items component in the page which calls the logout function, and images (items) are layed vertically when I click logout button.

here is my `Login.xhtml` page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<h:head> 
    <title>Login Page</title>

</h:head>
<h:body> 

    <h:form>
        Votre code alliance : #{loginBean.codeAliance} <br/> 
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5" >  

            <h:outputLabel for="codeAliance" value="Code Aliance:" />  
            <p:inputText value="#{userManager.codeAliance}" id="codeAliance" required="true" label="codeAliance" />

            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />  
            <p:password value="#{userManager.password}" id="password" required="true" label="password" />  

            <f:facet name="footer">  
                <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" action="#{userManager.connexion}" ajax="false"/>  
            </f:facet>  

        </h:panelGrid>             

    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

And here is `bienvenue.xhtml` page which contains `<p:dock>` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<h:head>
    <title>Premier exemple JSF 2.0</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form> 
        <p:dock position="top">  
            <p:menuitem value="Users" icon="/Images/Users.png" url="#"/>  
            <p:menuitem value="Quitter" icon="/Images/Logout.png" url="#"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Users" icon="/Images/Users.png" url="#"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Users" icon="/Images/Users.png" url="#"/> 

        </p:dock>
    </h:form>   
    <p:commandButton value="lyes" icon="/Images/Logout.png" action="#{userManager.logout}"/>
</h:body>
```

Can someone help me !?

Comment: Better you attach the `login.xhtml`.

Comment: Can you give me more explanations !?

Comment: Attach your `login.xhtml` in your answer if the components are strewed. The problem will be in that file I guess.

Comment: I have fixed the problem ! 
I added the `ajax` attribute set to `false` in the `<p:commandButton>`

Comment: Create an answer which contains the solution, let us know how you fixed it. Maybe another user is facing the same problem and he will be happy to see the solution.

Comment: I have just edit my last comment and have explain how I fixed the problem.